# Как реализовать взаимодействие классов в данном примере?

Tags: классы

Всем привет!
Требуется, что бы в классе Order , была возможность добавлять/удалять уже созданные классы Car и Manager. Подскажите как реализовать?

```
class Car {
        String model;
        String[] detali;
        int price;

        public Car(String model, int price) {
        }
    }

    class Manager {
        String name;
        String lastName;
        int id;

        public Manager(String name, String lastName, int id) {
        }
    }

    class Order {

**???**
    }

    Car bmw = new Car("i333", 2000000);
    Car lexus = new Car("dsx", 1999999);

    Manager ivanov = new Manager("Ivan", "Ivanov", 44);
    Manager petrov = new Manager("Petr", "Petrov", 43);
```

Comment: Не надо создавать людям проблемы: указывайте язык (что это с# или джава)

Comment: Используй в классе Order коллекции. И еще созданные классы называются объектами классов.